# Merge more than 3 Excel worksheets into one workbook with macro

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to merge worksheets together into one workbook. I have a work book that has over 20 sheets. I was looking to create a macro that would merge sheets together (depending on their name) into a separate workbook.

So far this is the code that I have got: it mergers all the sheets in the workbook together but I would like to merge them by name.

```
Sub mergedata()
  Sheets(1).Activate
  lastrow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
  For Each Sheet In Sheets
    If Sheet.Index <> 1 Then
      RowCount = Sheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
      Sheet.UsedRange.Copy Destination:=Sheets(1).Cells(lastrow + 1, 1)
      lastrow = lastrow + RowCount
      Sheet.UsedRange.Clear
    End If
  Next Sheet
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add one additional if statements in your loop. This could be like this:

```
'.....
For Each Sheet In Sheets
    If Sheet.Index <> 1 Then
        If Sheet.Name = "NameOfSheet" or Sheet.Name = "NameIsCaseSensitive" then
            RowCount = Sheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
            Sheet.UsedRange.Copy Destination:=Sheets(1).Cells(lastrow + 1, 1)
            lastrow = lastrow + RowCount
            Sheet.UsedRange.Clear
        end if
    End If
Next Sheet
'....
```

Comment: Thanks this works perfectly. Is there any way I could modify this to get the sheets that is combined to open in a separate workbook?

Comment: sorry, I don't get your comment question, could you clarify? if 'this works perfectly' why did you remove your answer acceptance?

Answer (score 0):

I case you need the same but horizontaly (like I did) (w/o Names upgrade)

```
Sub mergedata_horizontal()
  Sheets(1).Activate
  lastcol = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count
  For Each Sheet In Sheets
    If Sheet.Index <> 1 Then
      ColCount = Sheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count
      Sheet.UsedRange.Copy Destination:=Sheets(1).Cells(1, lastcol + 1)
      lastcol = lastcol + ColCount
      Sheet.UsedRange.Clear
    End If
  Next Sheet
End Sub
```